# Too many list items cause lag

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, virtualscroll

I am using `mat-expansion-panel` from `Angular Material` in my app and I combine it with `infinite scroll` so that I won't load all of them at once and it won't lag because of it. However, once I scroll to the bottom and I have about 30-40 elements loaded, it lags when I open the expansion panel.

My first solution to this was to use a `virtual-scroll`.

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll#usage

But it doesn't support variable height items.

My next solution was to use `infinite-scroll` on both directions, but I have never seen other apps make use of this so I think there should be a better way.

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll#usage

Has anyone else encountered this problem and solved it in a better way?

Comment: try html `details` tag. https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_summary.asp

Comment: There is some work of styling in this solution but I like it. It is very lightweight.

Comment: you can hide marker like this: `summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none
}` and do styling as you want.

Comment: Yes thanks I got that. I'm working on the styling now and I will make an animation for it. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use HTML Details Summary Tags:

Html:

```
<details>
  <summary>Your Heading</summary>
  <p> Your First Paragraph.</p>
  <p> Your Second Paragraph.</p>
</details>
```

CSS to hide default Marker: // you can style this as your want after this

```
summary::-webkit-details-marker { display: none }
```

> UPDATE for 2021:

to hide arrow use this css:

```
details > summary {
  list-style: none;
}
details > summary::marker {
  display: none;
}
```